# Bing Speech API with Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, bing-api

I am working on Xamarin Android application. Is there any way to use Bing Speech API with my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of using the [Bing Speech API](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api/documentation/overview). The first one is a [REST service](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api/documentation/API-Reference-REST/BingVoiceRecognition) which can be called from any Xamarin.Android application (no additional components required).

The other possibility is to use the client libraries. Microsoft provides libraries for C# (Windows Phone, WPF etc.), [Android](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api/documentation/getstarted/getstartedjavaandroid) and iOS. To use the library on your Xamarin.Android application, you can either try to use the C# library or create your own bindings for the Android specific Java library. Here's an article that'll help you with the binding:

[Binding a Java library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please send me link of any example related to this?

Comment: I don't have any examples, but you'll find sample code through the links I posted. Good luck!

Comment: I have one another question. It will be great if you can help me. 


@hankide



How to pass a data from .cs file to xaml.cs in Xamarin.Forms?

I used following approach.


Use MessagingCenter.Send<YourPage, YourObjcetType> (this, "NameOfMessage", YourObject); to send a message and pass the object you need. Then you can subscribe to this message in your other class:

MessagingCenter.Subscribe<YourPage, YourObjectType> (this, "NameOfMessage", (sender, arg) => {
 
});

Comment: If you're looking for an example of this being used, check out my SmartCoffee app, built with Xamarin.Forms. Includes dependency logic for recording audio, as well as REST wrapper for the Bing Speech API: https://github.com/pierceboggan/smartcoffee

Comment: Thank you for your response. @pierceboggan I have created Speech To Text application using Bing Speech API on Android and iOS platform successfully. I took reference of your SmartCoffee application. Now I want to add Windows Phone application. I have followed every steps which I found while searching on Google. But not get succeeded. Can you please guide me for that?